# Flash / as3: Where to put code for an intro movie clip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an .fla that links to a generic Document class which manages the UI and other MovieClips for a Flash movie.

If I want to add an intro movie without dynamically loading a different swf, where would I put the code for that?

Should I put it at the top of the Document class (in which case how would I make sure the clip finishes before I render the UI and add the event handlers?), or should I create an Intro class, link the .fla to THAT and have the Intro class load the Document class when the movie finishes?

Another way of phrasing this question would be: Should my .fla be linked to the first item that I need to load (in this case the movie) or should it link to a Document class that tells what to play and when?

Thanks!

Comment: Whats wrong with dynamically loading your intro movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpler things are the better 
and it seems simpler to have an instance of your intro in
your Document Class and control the flow from there.